# How can i fix css gradient?

Tags: html, css

can someone tell me why my gradient text css didn't work ?
i try to change color text to gradient but the color text still black

```css
.head{
    margin-top: 12rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(280deg, #27c1c3, #dd2dd5);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
 <h1 class="head">Hallo</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `-webkit-text-fill-color` property to your text

```css
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

```css
.head{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(280deg, #27c1c3, #dd2dd5);
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="head">Hallo</h1>
```